# Google map API in android studio gives error 'app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map and it generates an error....

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Using simple map activity and embed my API ki but it works.

Comment: use `multiDexEnabled true` in your app gradle( in defaultConfig).

Answer (score 0):

Enable multidex using following code :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```